# Find the limit of a very strange one

Tags: calculus, limits

I wonder how I can get the limit of 
$$
\sin \sqrt{n+1}-\sin\sqrt{n}
$$ 
when $n$ is approaching infinity?
I don't know the process of getting the answer.Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Use the trigonometric identity of the difference of two sines.

$$\sin A-\sin B=2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

Comment: I understand at once thank u

Answer (score 2):

Taking continuous variable in the function $\,f(x):=\sin\sqrt x\;$:

$$\left|\;\sin\sqrt{x+1}-\sin\sqrt x\;\right|=\left|\;\frac{\cos\sqrt c}{2\sqrt c}\;\right|\;,\;\;x<c<x+1$$

Now, when $\,x\to \infty\;$ then also $\,c\to\infty\;$ , but then

$$\left|\;\frac{\cos\sqrt c}{2\sqrt c}\;\right|\le\frac1{2\sqrt c}\xrightarrow[c\to\infty]{}0$$

so....

Comment: +1 This one is preferable since one can see what is going on inside the limit. Thanks Don.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \to 0$$ as $n \to \infty$ and apply the uniform continuity of $\sin$.